# Testing a car class Unittests

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, unit-testing, python-unittest

I keep getting 2 errors when I run the test. Test Results: test_details(Tests that the car details are correct) and test_price_reduction(Tests that the price reduction is recorded correctly)

Thanks for the help in advance.

I am testing this code:

```
import unittest

from car import Car


class TestCar(unittest.TestCase):
    """ Tests for the Car class """

    grade = 0

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        """ Sets up the Test Case """
        TestCar.grade = 0
        print("Grading your Car class... ")

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        """ Tears down the Test Case """
        print("Your grade for this part of the lab is: %d/8" % TestCar.grade)

    def setUp(self):
        """ Sets up the car objects to test in the subsequent tests """
        self.car1 = Car("Honda", "Civic", 2015, 4999.99, 9999.99)
        self.car2 = Car("Mazda", "Miata", 1990, 1500.0, 3999.88)

    def test_constructor(self):
        """ Tests that the car is successfully created """

        self.assertIsNotNone(self.car1)
        TestCar.grade += 1
        self.assertIsNotNone(self.car2)
        TestCar.grade += 1

    def test_details(self):
        """ Tests that the car details are correct """
        self.assertEqual("2015 Honda Civic for sale for $9999.99", self.car1.get_details())
        TestCar.grade += 1
        self.assertEqual("1990 Mazda Miata for sale for $3999.88", self.car2.get_details())
        TestCar.grade += 1

    def test_profit(self):
        """ Tests that the profit is calculated correctly """
        self.assertEqual(self.car1.calc_profit(), 5000.0)
        TestCar.grade += 1
        self.assertEqual(self.car2.calc_profit(), 2499.88)
        TestCar.grade += 1

    def test_price_reduction(self):
        """ Tests that the price reduction is recorded correctly """
        self.car1.reduce_price(1000.50)
        self.assertEqual(self.car1.calc_profit(), 3999.50)
        TestCar.grade += 1

        self.car2.reduce_price(999.88)
        self.assertEqual(self.car2.calc_profit(), 1500.0)
        TestCar.grade += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

With this code:

```
class Car:
    """ Represents a car in a car lot """

    def __init__(self, make, model, year, cost, price):
        """ Initializes the car details """
        self._make = make
        self._model = model
        self._year = year
        self._cost = cost
        self._price = price

    def calc_profit(self):
        """ Returns the projected profit """
        return self._price - self._cost

    def get_details(self):
        print(f"{self._year} {self._make} {self._model} for sale for ${self._price}")

    def reduce_price(self, reduction):
        self._price = self._cost - reduction


car1 = Car('Honda', 'Civic', 2015, 5000.00, 9999.99)
car1.calc_profit()
car1.get_details()
car1.reduce_price(1000.50)
print(car1._price)

car2 = Car('Mazda', 'Miata', 1990, 2499.88, 3999.88)
car2.calc_profit()
car2.get_details()
car2.reduce_price(999.88)
print(car2._price)

def main():
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my output:

```
2015 Honda Civic for sale for $9999.99
3999.5
1990 Mazda Miata for sale for $3999.88
1500.0
```

I keep getting 2 errors when I run the test.
Test Results: test_details(Tests that the car details are correct)
and
test_price_reduction(Tests that the price reduction is recorded correctly)

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `get_details()` function prints out a string using `print`. It does not return any value at all. When you have no `return` statement in a function the default return type is `None`. Which is why when you `self.assertEqual("2015 Honda Civic for sale for $9999.99", self.car1.get_details())` you fail the test. There is no way `"2015 Honda Civic for sale for $9999.99"` can equal `None`. You can update your get_details function to return a string instead of print it.

```py
def get_details(self):
    return f"{self._year} {self._make} {self._model} for sale for ${self._price}"
```

You will have to remember to update your usage from `car1.get_details()` to `print(car1.get_details())`

Your second issue is your `reduce_price` function sets your new price equal to the cost minus the reduction. I assume you meant to reduce the price by the old price minus the reduction.

```py
def reduce_price(self, reduction):
    self._price = self._price - reduction
```